# SVG path drawing and erasing animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm trying to do animation like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/e612vtms/)

```
.path {
    stroke-dasharray: 300;
    stroke-dashoffset: 300;
    animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
    50% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: -300;
    }
}
```

But the problem is IE support, so I think to use some JS library for animation. All the libraries I found could draw line, but not erase it like I want. Does anyone know anything that could help? I need IE10+ support

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [d3js](http://d3js.org/)

It is pretty much limitless once you get a grasp of how to use it

[This demo](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868) in particular might be useful to you

Hope this helps

EDIT: [This demo](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5649592) is even closer to what you are looking for